# Это умышленное минусование или случайное совпадение?

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Только что увидел такое сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня такой вопрос - это умышленное или случайное действие? Для случайного - слишком большое совпадение. Для умышленного - слишком мало минусов, всего лишь -8.

Comment: обычно если время одно и то же стоит - то большая вероятность, что серийный

Comment: собственно, на следующий день был откат этого серийного голосования

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Система посчитала, что голосование было серийным, и откатила голоса на следующий день:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]